# OneToMany Hibernate mapping using struts2

Tags: hibernate, struts2, one-to-many

I have a problem with OneToMany relationship in Hibernate using struts2

I've got 2 model objects UserDetails and Vehicle, and I have a bidirectional OneToMany relationship between this 2 object. And the problem is that I can't persist Vehicle Object whereas UserDetails is persisted. No compile or runtime errors... just vehicle table is empty

Here are my classes:

UserDetails.java

```
    package org.project.model;

/*imports... */

@Entity
@Table(name="user_details")
public class UserDetails {


    private int userId;
    private String userName;
        private Set<Vehicle> vehicle;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    public Set<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }

    public void setVehicle(Set<Vehicle> vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }   
}
```

Vehicle.java

```
    package org.project.model;

/*imports... */

@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

    private int vehicleId;
    private String vehicleName;
    private UserDetails user;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="vehicle_id")
    public int getVehicleId() {
        return vehicleId;
    }

    public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
    }

    @Column(name="vehicle_name")
    public String getVehicleName() {
        return vehicleName;
    }

    public void setVehicleName(String vehicleName) {
        this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_details")
    public UserDetails getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserDetails user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Action class

```
    package org.project.actions;

    /*imports...*/ 

    public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<UserDetails>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2167265047934268752L;

    private UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    private UserDetailsDao userDao = new UserDetailsDaoImpl( );
    private List<UserDetails> userList = new ArrayList<UserDetails>();

            /** PREVIOUS MISTAKE **/
            private Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();


    @Override
    public UserDetails getModel(){
        return user;
    }

    public String add() throws Exception {
                    /** PREVIOUS MISTAKE **/
                    vehicle.setUser(user);
                    user.getVehicle().add(vehicle);

            userDao.saveUser( user );
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String list() {
        userList = userDao.listUser();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String details() throws Exception {
        user = userDao.getUser();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String populate() throws InterruptedException{
        //...some population code...
        return "populate";
    }

    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public UserDetails getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserDetails user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<UserDetails> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<UserDetails> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }
}
```

and jsp page

```
    <!-- Head Section -->

<body>
    <s:form action="saveUser">
        <s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name"/>
        <s:textfield name="vehicle.vehicleName" label="Vehicle Name" />
        <s:submit value="Save"/>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found mistake. I forgot to initialize Vehicle object. But now I have another problem. What must be written in jsp file for vehicle? I can't   save vehicleName...

Comment: Hibernate and Struts2 have very little to do with each other, you should be able to partition the problems to show where the fault lies without entangling the two technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone. Now I found my mistake. I was implementing ModelDriven class. So i have duplicated values of vehicle. One from Action class second from model itself. And struts couldn't determine where to attach the input values... :)